# SALAMANDAR - strange text in links description in careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I noticed strange text "SALAMANDAR" in description of links in sections Writing and Reading on profile page. Is it a bug? Or what does it mean?

[image]

Example can be found in [my profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/agapitov).

Comment: A better question would be: Is [salamandar](https://www.google.com/search?q=salamandar&rlz=1C1PRFE_enIR614IR614&oq=salamandar&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.4728j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=salamandar&nfpr=1) a misspelling of salamander, a gift shop in UK, a cobra snake, a twitter username, a restaurant, or what?

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M - it is simply an anagram for "alas rad man"!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good spot! Fix going out to production now, it'll be build 3132 :)